# ReactJs problem setting up Environment variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables

I have a react project that I have on a vps.
I have two environment, dev and production and I want to add some Environment variable to know in which I am.

I tried to setup something like that in my package.json

```
"build:dev":  "REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT=dev react-scripts build",
"build:prod": "REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT=prod react-scripts build",
```

and use that as an indicator

```
<input type="hidden" defaultValue={process.env.REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT}/>
```

And it works quite well for production environment with a value of "prod".
But for some reason for the build:dev this value is undefined.

I can't understand why it's working for one but not the other.

**EDIT**

So i found out that the problem was me not setting the imagePullPolicy (kubernetes deployment part) for both part.
I assume that it worked with production because the tag latest should always be fetched I think whereas other tag not necessarily.

After putting "imagePullPolicy":"Always" everything seems ok whenever I deploy to both environments.

Comment: Are you serving `prod` and `dev` in the same way?

Comment: I have a kubernetes on my server and prod/dev represent a pod each served by different service/deployment
But both configs looks exactly the same, only the image used is different, one with the :latest tag for prod and :develop for dev

Comment: @Sonny - is dev being built in the pipeline - i.e. are you running `npm run build:dev` in the dev pipeline, or are you just perhaps starting it - `npm run start` in the container?

Comment: In my pipeline I have smth like this :  `if [ ${COMMIT-BRANCH-REF} == "master"]; then run npm build:prod; else run npm build:dev; fi; `